# Erro CS0266 Não é possível converter implicitamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Ao tentar fazer uma listagem onde filtrara apenas os 5 maiores registros por valores em ordem decrescente está me ocorrendo esse erro:

> Erro CS0266   Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo
>   "System.Linq.IQueryable" em
>   "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection".
>   Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?)

Aqui o meu código:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private NFeWebContext db = new NFeWebContext();
        // GET: Dashboard
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dashboard = new DashboardViewModel();
            var participantes = db.Participantes
                          .ToList();
            var notas = db.NotasFiscais
                          .ToList();
            var lista = db.NotasFiscais
                  .Where(x => db.Participantes.Any(y => y.ParticipanteId == x.ClienteID))
                  .GroupBy(z => z.ClienteID)
                  .Select(x => new NotaFiscal()
                  {
                      ClienteID = x.First().ClienteID,
                      ValorTotalNota = x.Sum(n => n.ValorTotalNota)
                  })
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota)
                  .Take(5);

            dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista;
            return View(dashboard);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brincar com LINQ sem entendê-lo bem não costuma dar boa coisa. Este código tem algumas coisas esquisitas, mas o maior problema é que a *query* não é está sendo materializada. Seria assim:

```
dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista.ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ToList.cs).